# ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on an `Asp.Net core 5` project.
In my project I use one `generic repository` and many `specific repositories`(All depend on `EF core`).

**I have this `IActionResult` :**

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Edit( int id )
        {
            var profAbsence = await _absenceRepository.GetByIdAsync( id , absence => absence.Prof , absence => absence.SchoolSubject );

            _model = _mapper.Map<ProfAbsenceVm>( profAbsence );

            await LoadForEditAsync();

            return View( _model );
        }
```

**`LoadForEditAsync` method's definition :**

```
async Task LoadForEditAsync()
{
    _model.Profs          = _mapper.Map<List<ProfVm>>( await _genericRepo.GetAsync<Prof>() );
    _model.Groups         = await _groupRepository.GetByProfAsync( _model.Prof.Id );
    _model.SchoolSubjects = await _schoolSubjectRepository.GetByGroupAsync( _model.GroupId );
}
```

**The problem :**
When try access to this `Action result` from `view` I got this error :

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A
> common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was
> resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the
> same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if
> you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a
> using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
> the dependency injection container take care of disposing context
> instances. Object name: 'AppDbContext'.

**Additional info:**
This `Controller` constructor should injected by my repositories services cause I registred them in the `Startup`

**A priece from the controller :**

```
private readonly ProfAbsenceRepository      _absenceRepository;
private readonly GroupRepository            _groupRepository;
private readonly SchoolSubjectRepository    _schoolSubjectRepository;
private readonly IGenericRepo<AppDbContext> _genericRepo;
private readonly IUowAsync<AppDbContext>    _uow;
private readonly IMapper                    _mapper;
private          ProfAbsenceVm              _model = new();


public ProfAbsenceController( ProfAbsenceRepository absenceRepository , IGenericRepo<AppDbContext> genericRepo , IUowAsync<AppDbContext> uow , IMapper mapper , GroupRepository groupRepository , SchoolSubjectRepository schoolSubjectRepository )
{
    _absenceRepository            = absenceRepository;
    _genericRepo                  = genericRepo;
    _uow                          = uow;
    _mapper                       = mapper;
    _groupRepository              = groupRepository;
    _schoolSubjectRepository = schoolSubjectRepository;
}
```

In `Startup` `ConfigureServices` method I registrd the services as :

```
// AppDbContext
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>( options => options
                                                           .UseSqlServer( Configuration
                                                                            .GetConnectionString( "DefaultConnection" ) )
                                                           .UseQueryTrackingBehavior( QueryTrackingBehavior
                                                               .NoTracking ) );

// Generic repository
services.AddScoped( typeof(IGenericRepo<AppDbContext>) , typeof(GenericRepo<AppDbContext>) );
    
                // Other repositories
                services.AddScoped<SchoolSubjectRepository>( x => new( x.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>() ) );
                services.AddScoped<ProfRepository>( x => new( x.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>() ) );
                services.AddScoped<ProfAbsenceRepository>( x => new( x.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>() ) );
                services.AddScoped<GroupRepository>( x => new( x.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>() ) );
                services.AddScoped<GroupProfSubjectRepository>( x => new( x.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>() ) );
```

Please any help to fix this issue ?

Comment: Your registration is a bit odd.  There is no reason to use a lambda to call the constructor of the repository, the DI framework knows how to do it.

Comment: @Neil I did it but the issue is still

Comment: Try to use the DI pattern to register the repository, instead of creating the repository instance and use the GetRequiredService() method, refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#overview-of-dependency-injection). If still not working, can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem.